# What is an appropriate debugging workflow for Powershell Core modules?

Tags: powershell, debugging, .net-core, powershell-cmdlet, powershell-core

My company has a .NET Powershell module, written in C# to allow advanced users to automate tasks in our product. Currently it targets Powershell 5 using .NET 4.6.1. We would like to allow customers using other operating systems to use it as well, and as it has no OS-specific code, porting it was straightforward.

However, I cannot find documentation on a debugging workflow that should be followed. In standard .NET Powershell, this was quite simple and required a one-time setup procedure:

- Configure the debug executable to be the Powershell path
- Set debug arguments to be a short script that loads the module and if appropriate, executes the function that is being tested.
- Hit F5

However, this doesn't work for Powershell Core. Because the project depends on NuGet packages, the module registration fails with a dependency error. I was able to figure out another workflow but it's a bit more obtuse:

- Navigate to the project directory
- Execute `dotnet publish -f netstandard2.0 -c debug`
- Execute `Import-Module ./bin/Debug/netstandard2.0/publish/MyModule.dll`
- Execute `$pid` to find the PID
- Attach to the PID via Attach to Process in Visual Studio

This works and I have debugged a few issues with this method, but it's not the most pleasant or efficient way to do it. I believe that there must be a better way that is just not well documented.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I originally came up with a script based approach that you can see in this post's history, but what I didn't know at the time was the `CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies` property which makes the debug directory look like how it used to look when working on .NET Framework. You just need to add this to your `.csproj` in a `<PropertyGroup>`:

```
<CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies>true</CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies>
```

Then, the debugging setup is just the same as any other .NET module loaded into a third party application:

1. Right click on your Powershell module project and click properties
2. Select Debug
3. Set Launch to Executable
4. Executable: `C:\Program Files\PowerShell\6\pwsh.exe`
5. Arguments: `-NoExit -Command "Import-Module C:\dev\my-module\bin\Debug\netstandard2.0\my-module.dll"`
6. Set your module as the startup project
7. Hit F5 to begin debugging.